# optimizing a special case in linkedlist by tail-building

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to build a list {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} by appending the nodes to the tail. For our client purposes, all the other nodes are inserted after the last node using a tail pointer.  The only "problem" with this solution is that coding separate special case for the first node can be optimized, and the client is pressing me. Nonetheless, this approach should be solid one for production code in theory...at least i thought until it keeps throwing null pointer exception when i get to the tail...am i missing something?

```
struct node* BuildWithSpecialCase() {
    struct node* head = NULL;
    struct node* tail;
    int i;

    Push(&head, 1);
    tail = head;

    for (i=2; i<6; i++) {
        Push(&(tail->next), i); 
    }
    return(head); 
}
```

Comment: In the loop, shouldn't you update `tail`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Why isn't that an answer instead of a comment :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg update to what?

Comment: You just keep on setting `tail->next` but the variable `tail` is never being changed, it's still pointing at `head`. After the call to `Push` do `tail = tail->next;`. Regarding the exception, have you run your program in a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your accessing pointers are traveling from the head to the tail, then adding nodes to the tail exposes them to "new" data that didn't exist at the time the "querying" of the list started.

Talk to your client, perhaps there is more than just "optimization" at stake.

--- Edited after seeing your code edit ---

Without an understanding of what `Push` is doing, I'll guess it's pushing a node on top of the linked list as if it were a stack.

```
Push(&head, 1);
tail = head;
```

So far, so good.

```
for (i=2; i<6; i++) {
    Push(&(tail->next), i); 
}
```

It appears that you just `Push`ed several nodes at tail, but I can't see where you actually updated the tail to maintain it's reference to the end of the list.  In my reading, `head` still points to the head of the list, `tail` still points to the head of the list (from the assignment `tail = head`) and you have a lot of "extra" nodes beyond tail.

Is that the problem?

Comment: yeah thats a good point..upvote on answer, and can you upvote my question too? thanks..